# How can I place my elements inside my navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

The elements of my navbar seem to be stuck outside of it. I'm not sure why?

Here's my code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse"></nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a
          style="color: black; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2rem;"
          class="navbar-brand"
          href="#"
          >name<span class="fas fa-microscope fa-1x"></span
        ></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Protect</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

```css
.nav a{
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand{
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

And here's what the navbar looks like:

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf52u.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this? (Also does the menu icon have a white background and is black, whereas the microscope icon has an invisible bg and is white?)

Thanks!

Comment: where css code ?

Comment: @AymanMorsy sorry, updated.

Answer (score 1):

You close the navbar in the beginning, so remove the `</nav>` tag from your first line.
Remove 2nd line, it is unnecessary code here.
Assign class "nav-link" for "Protect" & "About menu".

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a
          style="color: black; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2rem;"
          class="navbar-brand"
          href="#">name<span class="fas fa-microscope fa-1x"></span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Protect</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"  href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, how do I make it so that the navbar only shows up if the user is on mobile?